# Diacritic characters (ō, ó, á, ä, ö, ü etc) support in Debian shell

Tags: debian, locale, special-characters

I run a server on Debian as a file storage. Some files and directories contain those symbols in their name, and all those symbols get replaced with `?` (or `?` is what shell output shows me) when they get copied to the server through nfs or basically any other method. When I browse the mounted directory from my Windows machine through nfs it also shows me `?` instead of the characters.

The problem is that I can't force recheck imported directories because linux shell doesn't display the characters properly, so I can't have my files accessed and rechecked by my torrent client. Is there any workaround to fix the problem? I don't really think that there is a universal locale which contains all the diacritic characters. Many thanks.

EDIT:

`ls *name | hd`

`00000000                         3f 6e 61 6d 65 0a      |?name.|`

`00000006`

Comment: Your filenames are probably in some 8bit legacy encoding like `windows-1252`. There is a universal locale which contains ALL the diacritics: `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`, which is also the default on most recent distros. If it's also used on your machine, try `ls | iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8`, and see if the filenames are displayed correctly.

Comment: Actually I've had `en_GB.UTF-8` as my locale — I've changed it to `en_US.UTF-8`, tried the command (with `windows-1251` as well), but the symbol is still getting replaced with `?`.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls file*na*me | hd` to your Q (where you have replaced the runs of `?` with `*`). Notice that windows-125**2** is for West European / Latin1, windows-125**1** is for cyrillic ;-)

Comment: @Henry `en_GB.UTF-8` is good too

Comment: Added the output in my Q. Thanks for the locale remark though ;)

Comment: It looks like the filename either contains a literal `?`, or `ls` is some alias on your machine. Check if `/bin/ls *name` or other files than `*name` give you anything different than `3f`.

Comment: `/bin/ls *name` returns just '?name'

Comment: I should also mention that the situation is slightly more complicated — some files (which had German «ä») have gotten their «ä»'s replaced with a regular «a», and something had created a respective amount of 0 byte (copies, I guess?) of those files with the right names which have the right «ä». Though, that didn't happen with japanese «ō» — it still shows up as `?` with no «title-fixed» duplicate files as it happened to German characters.

Comment: I've mistaken when I told that the torrent client does recognize the `?`'s — it only shows the title taken from the .torrent file metadata, when I browse my directories with client's directory viewer it still shows `?` instead of `ō`. Apparently, linux does replace those symbols with `?` when a file gets copied to the server.

Comment: As I've figured out, empty files were created by the torrent client which had found most of the files (w/out the special characters) but didn't find the rest so it created the files so they would get downloaded when I resume the client.

Comment: So I guess that the torrent client mangled the names of the files it had created because of its mistaken idea that they're not supported on your system. Check its docs for how you can convince it that your system supports Unicode / UTF-8.

Comment: Probably I didn't make it clear (or I didn't quite understand what do you mean, anyway here's how it looks to me) — all the files were copied from my Windows machine through nfs protocol. Torrent client didn't mangle the names, the linux itself did mangle them (at the point when they first entered the server). Torrent client even created the right files with the right characters, so I guess the problem might be nfs or the system itself, the torrent client is working well. The empty files with the right name were created by the torrent client, not by nfs or linux itself.

Comment: Torrent client created the files with the right names (as if they were missing, in fact they ARE missing) because it couldn't find the files mangled by linux with regular `a`'s and `?` instead of the original `ä`'s and `ō`'s  respectively. The files are 0 bytes each because I have my downloads stopped. That's the situation.

Comment: SOLVED — Nfs was the source of the problem. I just tried to copy those files through ftp and the file names were preserved and torrent client has successfully verified the files. Thanks a lot for sticking around and sorry for wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Linux corrupted the files/directories names, but nfs. I copied the files through FTP and all the file names were preserved and the files had passed the validation. Apparently, nfs corrupts special/unusual characters if they appear in a file/directory name.